# Array slicing with data that contains multiple types

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I read in the following object with `numpy.genfromtxt`:

```
A = [(4, 'A', 3750.5), 
     (4, 'B', 3252.6),
     (8, 'A', 3350.5), 
     (8, 'B', 3152.6)]
```

I would like to do numpy fancy indexing on it, but I can't because this is not an numpy array. It's an array of a list.

What would be the best way to get the 3rd column of all rows that have '4' in the first column?

I tried `A[A[:,0]==4]` but the interpreter complained with "IndexError: invalid index".

Edit:

This is the python program I am using:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.genfromtxt( "text.txt" , dtype=( int , "|S10", float))

A_array = np.asarray(A, dtype=object)

print A
print A_array
```

The file `text.txt`:

```
4 A 3750.5
4 B 3270.5
8 A 3480.5
8 B 3590.5
```

This is the output:

```
[(4, 'A', 3750.5) (4, 'B', 3270.5) (8, 'A', 3480.5) (8, 'B', 3590.5)]
[(4, 'A', 3750.5) (4, 'B', 3270.5) (8, 'A', 3480.5) (8, 'B', 3590.5)]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `A` is actually a list of tuples, not an array of lists.

Comment: Why did someone insert commas into A? If I print A there are no commas. Is it maybe a list of tuples?

Comment: You used `A = ...` implying that you're assigning the data. When you "print" data, you don't say `A = ...`, you just print the contents. When you assign to a variable with `A = ...` you need the value on the right-hand-side of the `=` symbol to evaluate to a valid Python object, which is not true without the commas.

Comment: I will try to insert commas as needed. I explained it the wrong way. The first matrix was the output of a print command. The question is updated. Sorry

Comment: Ok. Do you agree that A_array and A would print exactly the same?

Comment: No, definitely not. `A_array` should print in aligned columns with an extra display for `dtype`, whereas `A` will print just as a plain Python `list` always prints.

Comment: @EMS, no, you are confusing `repr` and `str` I think.

Comment: @seberg No. While `repr` does print `ndarray` *with* commas, it has no relevance on a question about how a `list` is printed vs. a `numpy.ndarray` of that `list`.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [24]: A_array = numpy.asarray(A, dtype=object)

In [25]: A_array[A_array[:,0] == 4]
Out[25]:
array([[4, A, 3750.5],
       [4, B, 3252.6]], dtype=object)
```

If the columns of data have semantic meaning that you'd like to keep track of, consider loading the list of tuples directly into a [Pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html) and giving them column labels. The logical indexing would work similarly:

```
In [27]: A_df = pandas.DataFrame(A, columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])

In [28]: A_df
Out[28]:
   Col1 Col2    Col3
0     4    A  3750.5
1     4    B  3252.6
2     8    A  3350.5
3     8    B  3152.6

In [29]: A_df.Col1 == 4
Out[29]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: Col1

In [30]: A_df[A_df.Col1 == 4]
Out[30]:
   Col1 Col2    Col3
0     4    A  3750.5
1     4    B  3252.6
```

Comment: Hmm.. I tried your first solution. When I print A and A_array they appear exactly the same, and the indexing command on A_array fails as it does on A.

Comment: Your comment is ambiguous unless I can see the specific code you're executing. It works for me, and is indeed the standard solution for this in `numpy`.

Comment: Also, if `A` and `A_array` appear the same when you use `print` to print them out, you must have another error. The first, being just a Python `list` will print to the console very differently than the second, which is a `numpy.ndarray`. For instance, `A_array` will always some `dtype` field printed along with its actual data contents, whereas that doesn't exist for a `list`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need commas between the list elements in `A`, otherwise you'll get a syntax error:

```
A = [(4, 'A', 3750.5),
     (4, 'B', 3252.6),
     (8, 'A', 3350.5), 
     (8, 'B', 3152.6)]
```

Next, you can use a [*list comprehension*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get what you want pretty succinctly:

```
[ row[2] for row in A if row[0] == 4 ]
```

Result:

```
[3750.5, 3252.6]
```